# Is it possible to add new state-store to topology in runtime

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Is there any way to add new state-store to topology and connect with processor in runtime without closing KafkaStreams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no we can't, the reason being

When using Kafka Streams, you normally don’t create or instantiate state stores directly in your code. Rather, you define state stores indirectly by creating a so-called StoreBuilder. This builder is used by Kafka Streams as a factory to instantiate the actual state stores locally in application instances when and where needed.